# Supporting toggle between new file-types in eclipse or eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I would like to extend the source/header toggle functionality of eclipse CDT for custom file types. I work with *.cppml and *.hppml file extensions (C++ with some functional language syntax-extension), and I would like eclipse to understand that there is a source/header relationship between these two file types and toggle between them upon request.

Comment: Have you already set up the cppml and hppml as source and header content types? like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474629/is-ecplise-cdts-indexer-limited-to-the-common-filetypes-for-sources-and-headers

Comment: I have indeed added `cppml` and `hppml` as C++ Source and C++ header user-defined file-types to enable syntax highlighting.

Comment: So, I am working in a mixed source tree (C++/python) and I had the project set up as a python project, but the perspective as a CDT perspective. Ctrl+Tab was not working for cpp/hpp files either. I had to make create a C++ version of the project to get Ctrl+Tab to work for cpp/hpp and it actually also works for cppml/hppml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current CDT does not support this exactly, but it is pretty close, it needs an update to [`SourceHeaderPartnerFinder`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/editor/SourceHeaderPartnerFinder.java).

That class has a method, [`getPartnerFileFromFilename`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/editor/SourceHeaderPartnerFinder.java#n279), which calculates the partner when you do a Header/Source toggle (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> by default, or available from *Navigate* -> *Toggle Source/Header*)

That method strips off the extension of the file you started in, and then tries the partner type extensions (as derived from [`getPartnerContentTypes`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/editor/SourceHeaderPartnerFinder.java#n245)).

What needs to be done is update `getPartnerFileFromFilename` to create new header/source partnerships. Perhaps you could even edit the `File Types` property pages to allow users to explicitly define such associations.

If this feature is of value to you, raising it in [CDT's Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT&component=cdt-editor) would be a good start.